# Basic pointer/reference issue in Objective-C - accessor methods in one instance affect all instances at class level

Tags: objective-c

I am having trouble with what I suspect is a basic error in my understanding of how pointers and references are used in Objective-C.  I keep looking at the issue, tweaking my code, etc, etc... to no avail.

I KNOW that I am making a simple error somewhere (newbie to Objective-C, but not to OOP) but just I don't see it... argh  :P

I welcome any and all input from the much wiser such as yourselves. :)

If I may illustrate my problem it goes something like this :

In my "main.m" file I instantiate 4 separate instances of a certain "Rectangle" class, each one with unique dimensions and cartesian coordinates accessible via getter(s)/setter(s).
"width" and "height" properties are synthesized while coordinates are wrapped inside an object (XYPpoint class) accessible via custom methods.

When I access width and height properties I am able to get/set unique values for any and all instances, however when I try that with the coordinates I inevitably end up changing them for all instances at the same time.

What am I doing wrong? I can see that my origin object instantiates only 1 (instead of 4 tmes) but I don't see why?!?

*****EDIT:
As per hamstergene's kind suggestion (see 1st answer) I tried it again and got it to work by declaring *origin as a @property. However I then also had to @synthesize it first it and THEN overwrite it in @implementation. I don't know why but that just seems a bit like overkill to me.  Is it the correct way?  Also Xcode doesn't seem to like it and throws an alert (still compiles though)

---

As for the code here it is (short):

==================================================================================

## (interface for wrapper class of the coordinates object)

```
//  XYPoint.h
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface XYPoint : NSObject

@property float x, y;

-(void) setX: (float) xVal andY: (float) yVal;

@end
```

==================================================================================

## (implementation for wrapper class of the coordinates object)

```
//  XYPoint.m
//

#import "XYPoint.h"

@implementation XYPoint

@synthesize x, y;

-(void) setX: (float) xVal andY: (float) yVal {
    x = xVal;
    y = yVal;
}

@end
```

==================================================================================

## (interface for my Rectangle class)

```
//  Rectangle.h
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "XYPoint.h"

@interface Rectangle : NSObject

@property   float   width,
                    height;

-(XYPoint *)    origin;
-(void)         setWidth: (float) w andHeight: (float) h;
-(void)         setOrigin: (XYPoint *) pt;
-(void)         printData;

@end
```

==================================================================================

## (implementation for my Rectangle class)

```
//  Rectangle.m
//

#import "Rectangle.h"

@implementation Rectangle

@synthesize width, height;

XYPoint *origin;

-(void) setWidth:(float) w andHeight: (float) h {
    width = w;
    height = h;
}

-(XYPoint *) origin {
    return origin;
}

-(void) setOrigin: (XYPoint *) pt {

    if ( ! origin ) {
        NSLog( @"origin object created" );
        origin = [ [ XYPoint alloc ] init ];
    }
    origin.x = pt.x;
    origin.y = pt.y;
}

-(void) printData {
    NSLog( @"origin coordinates ( %.1f, %.1f )", origin.x, origin.y );
    NSLog( @"Width = %.1f, Height = %.1f\n" );
}

@end
```

==================================================================================

## (and finally main.m)

```
//  main.m
//

#import "Rectangle.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    @autoreleasepool {

        XYPoint     *rect1Origin    = [ [ XYPoint alloc ] init ];
        XYPoint     *rect2Origin    = [ [ XYPoint alloc ] init ];
        XYPoint     *rect3Origin    = [ [ XYPoint alloc ] init ];
        XYPoint     *rect4Origin    = [ [ XYPoint alloc ] init ];
        Rectangle   *rect1          = [ [ Rectangle alloc ] init ];
        Rectangle   *rect2          = [ [ Rectangle alloc ] init ];
        Rectangle   *rect3          = [ [ Rectangle alloc ] init ];
        Rectangle   *rect4          = [ [ Rectangle alloc ] init ];

        [ rect1Origin setX: 200 andY: 420 ];
        [ rect1 setOrigin: rect1Origin ];
        [ rect1 setWidth: 250 andHeight: 75 ];
        NSLog( @"1st Rectangle\n------------------------------------------" );
        [ rect1 printData ];

        [ rect2Origin setX: 400 andY: 300 ];
        [ rect2 setOrigin: rect2Origin ];
        [ rect2 setWidth: 100 andHeight: 180 ];
        NSLog( @"2nd Rectangle\n------------------------------------------" );
        [ rect2 printData ];

        [ rect3Origin setX: 99 andY: 99 ];
        [ rect3 setOrigin: rect3Origin ];
        [ rect3 setWidth: 50 andHeight: 450 ];
        NSLog( @"3rd Rectangle\n------------------------------------------" );
        [ rect3 printData ];

        [ rect4Origin setX: 20 andY: 100 ];
        [ rect4 setOrigin: rect4Origin ];
        [ rect4 setWidth: 10 andHeight: 3 ];
        NSLog( @"4th Rectangle\n------------------------------------------" );
        [ rect4 printData ];

        NSLog( @"\n------------------------------------------" );
        NSLog( @"1st Rectangle again...\n------------------------------------------" );
        [ rect1 printData ];

        NSLog( @"2nd Rectangle again...\n------------------------------------------" );
        [ rect2 printData ];

        NSLog( @"3rd Rectangle again...\n------------------------------------------" );
        [ rect3 printData ];

        NSLog( @"4th Rectangle again...\n------------------------------------------" );
        [ rect4 printData ];

        NSLog( @"\n\n********* All rects have the same coordinates why does this happen?" );

    }
    return 0;
}
```

==================================================================================

## OUTPUT

```
origin object created
1st Rectangle
------------------------------------------
origin coordinates ( 200.0, 420.0 )
Width = 250.0, Height = 75.0

2nd Rectangle
------------------------------------------
origin coordinates ( 400.0, 300.0 )
Width = 100.0, Height = 180.0

3rd Rectangle
------------------------------------------
origin coordinates ( 99.0, 99.0 )
Width = 50.0, Height = 450.0

4th Rectangle
------------------------------------------
origin coordinates ( 20.0, 100.0 )
Width = 10.0, Height = 3.0

------------------------------------------
1st Rectangle again...
------------------------------------------
origin coordinates ( 20.0, 100.0 )
Width = 250.0, Height = 75.0

2nd Rectangle again...
------------------------------------------
origin coordinates ( 20.0, 100.0 )
Width = 100.0, Height = 180.0

3rd Rectangle again...
------------------------------------------
origin coordinates ( 20.0, 100.0 )
Width = 50.0, Height = 450.0

4th Rectangle again...
------------------------------------------
origin coordinates ( 20.0, 100.0 )
Width = 10.0, Height = 3.0


********* All rects have the same coordinates why does this happen?
```

Comment: For what its worth, these classes (actually structs) already exist in CoreGraphics. Look at CGPoint and CGRect

Comment: Thank you James. Building these classes was actually part of an exercise as per this book I'm reading  (Steve Kochan's "Programming in Objective-C") :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what I did wrong.  Using the @property/@synthesize directives works fine but technically the issue was a simple syntax problem that changed the scope of the variable *origin in my Rectangle.m implementation.

Basically all I needed to do was to encase the variable declaration between curly quotation marks  (without them I was inadvertently setting *origin as global.)

So basically instead of this :

```
//=======================================    
@implementation Rectangle    
//=======================================    

@synthesize width, height;    

XYPoint *origin;
```

I should have done this:

```
//=======================================  
@implementation Rectangle  
//=======================================  
{  
XYPoint *origin;  
}  

@synthesize width, height;
```

Et voila' - problem solved.  Thanks to David Todd (from : http://classroomm.com/objective-c/index.php?topic=9389.0) for his solution (and again to hamstergene and rob mayoff here)

Answer (score 3):

`XYPoint *origin;` is a global variable, which means it is shared throughout whole program. You need to declare it as a property, just like you did with `x`, `y`, `width` and `height`.

Comment: Remove global variable declaration, remove custom getter and setter, add `@property` and `@synthesize` clauses.

Comment: Or just make it an instance variable (“ivar”).

Comment: Thank you again hamstergene and rob.  Is there a reason why I need to synthesize *origin and then overwrite it, as opposed to just use custom getter/setters (ie not synthesized properties)?